# Prevent map refresh when marker moves - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a geolocation map where the user can select a location from a dropdown, this then adds the location to the map as a marker. However I have just implemented code to update the geolocation of the person if they are moving, on this function update it refreshes the entire map and removes the marker of the location.

Is there a way around this whole map refresh, something like updating just the marker postion without refreshing the whole map or is it simply a case of grabbing the location before refresh then adding it back in afterwards? 
This seems wasteful on resources though as it updates every 3 seconds.

Example Google Maps API code would be great as I don't currently have mine to hand to show as example.

Summary: I wish to be able to update the user position marker without refreshing the whole map div as this then removes any previously added markers.

Thanks

Comment: It'll be hard to answer this without seeing what your code is doing so far

Answer (score -2):

I think there is a lot of different way to prevent that. check out the google.maps.Map class and its methods in the API documentation.